# Why the react part cannot get the server data

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios

Server is written on Node.js and client on react. the server has login logic using steam. logged in user's data is stored on route "/" or Url 'https://reviews-server-mern-steam.onrender.com/' (server) and has this structure:{"provider":"steam","_json":{"steamid":"privateInfo","communityvisibilitystate":3 ............}. After logging the data appears on 'https://reviews-server-mern-steam.onrender.com/' (I manually went to the server url), but the client logs show 'GET
'server URL' 'No user authenticated''.
client url-'https://reviews-client-mern-steam.onrender.com/'
piece of server code

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new SteamStrategy(
    {
      returnURL:
        "serverURL/api/auth/steam/return",
      realm: "serverURL",
      apiKey: "privateInfo",
    },
    function (identifier, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        profile.identifier = identifier;
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    }
  )
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "privateInfo",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3600000,
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening, port " + port);
});

app.use(express.json());
// Routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.send(req.user);
  } else {
    res.send("No user authenticated");
  }
});

app.get(
  "/api/auth/steam",
  passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("clientUrl");
  }
);

app.get(
  "/api/auth/steam/return",
  passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("clientUrl");
  }
);

app.post("/api/save-input-review", (req, res) => {
  const review = new Review(req.body);

  review
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error saving review:", error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

piece of react code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("serverUrl", {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const loggedInValue = response.data.photos[2].value ? true : false;
        setLoggedIn(loggedInValue);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Postman shows that 'serverUrl' has no response, but 'serverUrl' has data (visiting manually).
I have guesses thats because '/api/get-all-reviews' is same for all users and '/' is dynamic. so, maybe, client just dont know from what server session to grab json data (as postman)